# How can I start a totally independentt new instance of tmux?

Tags: linux, terminal, tmux

If I have already a tmux session opened, results that I can't start a new one with another tmux configuration, for ie:

```
$ tmux # loads new session using ~/.tmux.conf
```

In another terminal...

```
$ tmux -f another.tmux.conf
( load the same tmux configuration )
```

I tried using `tmux -f another.tmux.conf new-session -s another`, but it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 6):

The *quid* here is that even when you open a new session, all of them belong to the same "server". The only way to overcome this seems using another socket with:

```
tmux -f another.tmux.conf -L new-socket
```

If you want to list sessions for the new instance, you have to add the named socket or will list only the default one.

```
tmux -L new-socket list-sessions
```

Relevant part of this info it's on the [tmux man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/tmux.1.html) under the description of its arguments:

```
-L socket-name
               tmux stores the server socket in a directory under
               TMUX_TMPDIR, TMPDIR if it is unset, or /tmp if both are
               unset.  The default socket is named default.  This option
               allows a different socket name to be specified, allowing
               several independent tmux servers to be run.  Unlike -S a
               full path is not necessary: the sockets are all created in
               the same directory.

               If the socket is accidentally removed, the SIGUSR1 signal
               may be sent to the tmux server process to recreate it.
```

This means you can't communicate between two different tmux instances (afaik).